# I can't see the tabBarLabel fully

Tags: react-native

[image]

it's tabbar, but their title are shown not fully

there is a piece of code

```
<ClientTabs.Screen 
        name="MapScreen"
        component={MapScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown:false,
          tabBarLabel: 'Карта',
           tabBarLabelStyle:{fontSize:12},  allowFontScaling:false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Icon name="map-marker"
              type="material-community"
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Is the title too long? What you wanna reach line breaks? That the text extend the tab width?

Comment: the title is not long, I do not know why the title is not shown

Answer (score 0):

My guess is add flex:1 to give the label all space needed:

```
<ClientTabs.Screen 
        name="MapScreen"
        component={MapScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown:false,
          tabBarLabel: 'Карта',
          tabBarLabelStyle:{fontSize:12, flex:1}, //add flex:1
          allowFontScaling:false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Icon name="map-marker"
              type="material-community"
              color={color}
              size={size}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue, and it was resolved by adding the following line:

`tabBarLabelStyle: { minWidth: 70 },`